# Cannot delete empty SQL Server Broker Queues

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have queues created in proper order like so:

```
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE MyMessageType AUTHORIZATION dbo VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML
GO
CREATE CONTRACT MyMessageContract AUTHORIZATION [dbo] (MyMessageType SENT BY INITIATOR)
GO
CREATE QUEUE [dbo].[MyMessageQueue] WITH STATUS = ON , RETENTION = OFF 
GO
CREATE SERVICE [MyMessageService] ON QUEUE [dbo].[MyMessageQueue] (MyMessageContract)
```

The issue I'm having is when I try delete them all. I start with dropping the service first or contract first or any other one at first, it doesn't matter, I cannot delete.

Any tips?

Please note that the the queue is EMPTY..

Thanks!

Comment: You must delete the service first. What error do you get when you try to delete it?

Comment: I tried to delete the service first. There's no error, it just hangs i.e. keeps waiting for something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a patching issues. We applied all the latest patches and the issue disappeared.